# Link or alias user account in Jenkins to TFS user account

Tags: jenkins, tfs, user-management

Jenkin shows two accounts for the same person, one from Active Directory and one from Team Foundation Server (TFS).

- When I checkin code, a build is triggered (in this case `Main - Build` config) and the changes show user `windows live id_steven@example.com` with email address `Windows Live ID\steven@example.com`
- When I click Build Now in Jenkins, it shows the changes came from user `ssteven` with email address `Steven@Example.com`

How can I link these two accounts since they are both the same person?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible with the [Additional Identities Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Additional+Identities+Plugin) to merge accounts by matching various properties, e.g. TFS account ID.

However, this may not work in all cases and is generally a long-outstanding issue in Jenkins:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10258